# Limit of independent sequence of Normal Distribution is Chi Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, central-limit-theorem

I am looking for some help to solve the following central limit theory question below

Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ be i.i.d. with $X_i ≥ 0$, $EX_i = 1$, and  $\operatorname{var} (X_i) = \sigma^2  \in (0, \infty)$. Show that 
$2\left(\sqrt{S_n} − \sqrt{n}\right) \Rightarrow \sigma \chi $.

Answer (score 1):

You know that 
$$
\sqrt{n}\left(\frac {S_n}n - 1\right) \to G\sim N(0,\sigma^2)
$$Then via [delta method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method):

$$2\left(\sqrt{S_n} - \sqrt{n}\right)=
2\sqrt{n}\left(\sqrt{\frac {S_n}n} - 1\right) \to G'\sim N(0,\sigma^2)
$$

Comment: Thank you  for your help. I am not familiar with the delta method you used actually. if i would solve it in more steps do you have an idea what it is ?

Comment: Just take a look at the demonstration of the delta method, this is more or less the Taylor formula.

Comment: thanks, does the scalar "2" have any effects here ?

Comment: yes, it simplifies with the derivative of $\sqrt{}$ in $x=1$.